# What is the best way to get content of a div as an image without loosing the quality

Tags: html5-canvas, html2canvas

I have a DIV who's size may vary depending on the size of the window.
What I'm trying to get is the image version of div (as if the user took a screenshot of that div) but always in 1280x720 resolution.

One option I'm trying is to dump DIV content in canvas using html2canvas library but when I scale it up, I lose the image quality. Is there any alternative for that?

Answer (score 0):

`<img src="path/filename.extension" style="min-width:100%;" />`

this will fit image in parent div (whatever size it gets).

Comment: Sorry. Didn't get you. You mean Blockquote is a library?

Comment: Crap! i added a code *<img src="path/filename.extension" style="min-width:100%;" />

Comment: ah! this stretches the image. I want the actual image in 1280x720.

So basically I want to scale the image but onrendered callback of html2canvas doesn't give canvas object which has scale method in it.

Comment: This will fit your image in 1280x720 (suppose it is 4000x3000 or 800x300) but it won't downsample it to 1280x720. I suppose you are trying to downsample image anysize to 120x720.

Comment: No. I am upscaling it from 960x540 to 1280x720. But it's not able displaying image in that size in DOM but getting the actual image (base64 encoded data) in 1280x720 so if I create an image from that base64 encoded data, I get the image of size 1280x720.